# How to keep the dot in filename in GNU Make

Tags: windows, makefile, gnu

I have a variable

```
SRC = file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv
```

If I `echo $(subst .csv,.,$(SRC))` or `echo $(subst csv,,$(SRC))`, I'll get

```
file1 file2 file3
```

What I looking for is

```
file1. file2. file3.
```

But GNU make keep stripping the dot. How to solve this?

---

**Add**:

My real lines has extra things like this:

```
SRC = $(shell dir /b /s $(SRC_ROOT)\*.csv))
echo $(subst .csv,.,$(basename $(notdir $(SRC))))
```

Comment: That isn't happening here. I get your expected output (as I should) what version of GNU make are you using?

Comment: GNU Make for Windows v3.81 from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm. Sort of legacy build system so I can't update the version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: Thanks guys, MadScientist was right, I have some additional `$(basename $(notdir` in the line that causes the problem. Below is my real lines and with MadScientist's sharp eye and comment, my solution turn out like this:

```
SRC = $(shell dir /b /s $(SRC_ROOT)\*.csv))
echo $(patsubst %csv,%,$(notdir $(SRC)))
```

Comment: This is not right.  First, there are no directories in your `SRC` variable, so `$(notdir $(SRC))` is identical to `$(SRC)`.  Second, there is only one suffix on your `SRC` values so `$(basename ...)` will give you `file1 file2 file3`.  That means that the `$(patsubst ...)` won't do anything (it's a no-op).  That's why you need to use the `addsuffix` (I assume you meant `addsuffix` even though you wrote `addprefix`) to add back the `.`.  If you need to remove directories (_you should use them in the example!_) use `$(patsubst %csv,%,$(notdir $(SRC)))`

Comment: @MadScientist Good catch `addsuffix` it was. So I removed `addsuffix` + `basename` based on your comment. And `patsubst` + `notdir` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Etan, your example works fine.  I think you're doing something different in real life than you've described here.

I'll note though that using `subst` is a bad idea.  If you had a file like `cacsv20.csv` then `subst` on `csv` would do the wrong thing.

I suggest you use `patsubst`, such as: `$(patsubst %csv,%,$(SRC))`

ETA: based on the updated question, you probably want:

```
SRC := $(shell dir /b /s $(SRC_ROOT)\*.csv))
BASE := $(patsubst %csv,%,$(notdir $(SRC)))
```

Use the `notdir` to take off the directory name, and the `patsubst` (not `basename`) to remove the suffix, since you want to keep the trailing period.

Note I'm using `:=` rather than `=`; except in very special situations you always want to use `:=` when you use `$(shell ...)`, for performance reasons.

Comment: Tried that result's the same with `patsubst`.

Comment: But you are right about additional thing I've put in. The real life was something like this: `echo $(subst .csv,.,$(basename $(notdir $(SRC))))`. The `$(basename $(notdir` was the cause of the problem.

Comment: Hm, I feel that's not right in SO just to post my answer like that and keep editing it with your comment and without proper explain it in my question. And credit should goes to you in helping me to find the answer. Could you update your answer and let me accept it as answer?